# Multiple forms vs Single form with multiple initiations

Tags: vb.net, forms, vba

This is a question that is bugging me for a long time in every .net like enviroment (vb, vba, etc.).

What is a better programing practice: have multiple forms with each of them having same layout (buttons, fields,etc) but each of them doing something a little differently, or create a single form that every time is loaded for a different situation has to load a different dataset with a different SQL query?

I will give the following example to clarify the above situation.

I have two types of users. User1 and User2. Both of them could open a form but the first user (User1) must open it read only while the second user (User2) could make changes in the data. Is it better here to have the same form for both of them and when it loads check if user1 or user2 has open it and disable the or enable the fieds accordingly or have two different forms for the same thing but form1 has fields disabled by default and form 2 controls are enabled by default.

The above situation is really simple and I think that the answer is a single form. But what if the situation is more complicated? (Some fields must be enabled to one, others to the other one, different sql queries for both of them, different datatypes between users, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is just about configuring the *same* behaviour in a couple of different ways I would come up with creating a configuration structure to describe whether fields should be visible or not (desirably linked to your business model).

Your code would be like this (VB.Net):

```
Public Structure UserConfiguration
    Public Dim IsAdministrator As Boolean
    '...
End Structure

Public Class UserForm
    Public Sub New(ByVal configuration as UserConfiguration)
        SearchTextBox.Enabled = configuration.IsAdministrator
    End Sub
End Class
```

And then call it like

```
Dim config as New UserConfiguration()
config.IsAdministrator = true
Dim form as new UserForm(config)
form.Show()
```

**But** if you assume there could be a bunch of scenarios where your form's *behaviour* would be different, you should probably come up with [inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973803.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
Public Class BaseForm
   'Some code common for all forms that will inherit from this one
End Class

Public Class AdministratorForm
    Inherits BaseForm
     Public Sub New()
        SearchTextBox.Enabled = True
        MsgBox("Hello, I am an administrator!")
    End Sub
End Class
```

All in all the rule of thumb is to stick to [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself). If you know your forms will share the same piece of code but still have behaviour difference, you don't want to copy-paste your code twice.

Comment: That actually is a great answer and what I was hoping for! However I will not accept it just yet because I would like to see what others think also about this issue if it is ok with you! Thanks a lot anyway!!!